# yii tbgridview. showing only paritcular row data

Tags: php, gridview, yii, datagridview

I have a inventory table. Now, using this table, I want to show the data on Pharmacy module in a Tbgridview such that it only displays those inventories from the Pharmacy store. i.e. row with `category_id=2`.

How, can I do this on the drug's index page. This is the code for index page of Pharmacy.

```
<?php
    $this->menu=array(
        array('label'=>'Add Drug', 'icon'=>'icon-plus', 'url'=>Yii::app()->controller->createUrl('create'), 'linkOptions'=>array()),
        array('label'=>'List Drugs', 'icon'=>'icon-th-list', 'url'=>Yii::app()->controller->createUrl('index'),'active'=>true, 'linkOptions'=>array()),
        array('label'=>'List Orders', 'icon'=>'icon-th-list', 'url'=>Yii::app()->controller->createUrl('PhOrder/index'), 'linkOptions'=>array()),
        array('label'=>'List Distributors', 'icon'=>'icon-th-list', 'url'=>Yii::app()->controller->createUrl('PhDistributor/index'), 'linkOptions'=>array()),
    );
?>
<div>
    <?php  ?>

    <?php
    $model= new Inventory;

    $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView',array(
        'id'=>'ph-drug-grid',
        'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
        'type'=>'bordered condensed',
        'template'=>'{summary}{pager}{items}{pager}',
        'columns'=>array(
            array(
                'header'=>'<a href="#">S. N. </a>',
                'value'=>'$data->inventory_code',
                'type'=>'raw',
            ),
            'description',
            'manufacturer',

            'minimum_order_level',
            'store_id',
            'stock_quantity',

            array(
                'header'=>'<a>Actions</a>',
                'class'=>'bootstrap.widgets.TbButtonColumn',
                'template' => '{dispose}',
                'buttons' => array(
                    'dispose' => array(
                        'label'=>'Dispose',
                        'options'=>array(
                            'class'=>'btn btn-small',
                            'onclick'=>'return confirm("Are you sure, you want to dispose this drug?")'
                        ),
                    )
                ),
                'htmlOptions'=>array('nowrap'=>'nowrap'),
            )
        ),
    )); ?>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set attributes of your model, then if they are filtered in `search()` function of model `Inventory`, then result will get filtered

```
$model= new Inventory;
$model->category_id = 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also use CSqlDataProvider in your controller

```
$sql='select * from inventory where category_id=2';
$count=Yii::app()->db->createCommand('select count(*) from inventory where category_id=2')->queryScalar();
$dataProvider = new CSqlDataProvider($sql, array(
                           'totalItemCount'=>$count,
                           'keyField' => 'id',
                           'pagination'=>array(
                                  'pageSize'=>10,
                           ),
                    ));
```

[more info](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/639/csqldataprovider-in-cgridview/)

Comment: tonnes of thanks to you.. this one is exactly what I wanna do.